# Trace impedance on 4layers (Top and internal_plane_1)

Tags: pcb-design, controlled-impedance, layers

I'm currently design a 4layers pcb with 50r trace for an Ceramic chip antenna (on top layer).
Due of a lot of trace, my trace antenna is a coplanar.
Trace on top layer with polygon pour around AND internal_plane_1 (just below) connected to gnd.

The calculation: [https://chemandy.com/calculators/coplanar-waveguide-with-ground-calculator.htm[[1](https://chemandy.com/calculators/coplanar-waveguide-with-ground-calculator.htm)
With E = 4 / S = 0.37 / W = 0.154 / h = 0.2.
Impedance >> 50.0r

My question. We see often impedance controled track with Top and Bot layer, rarely with top and internal plane.
is there a contraindication ?

Comment: " ...impedance controled track with Top and Bot layer...".  Do you mean running a trace on the top or bottom layer (1 or 4 in your case), with a reference plane internal to the PCB (layer 2 or 3)?  I'm confused about the last question.  Also, a sketch or picture would help.

Comment: generally, the track is on top with polygon pour around, nothing inside (no internal plane) and polygon pour on bottom. In my project, i would design my circuit as : Track with polygon pour around, and polygon pour in first internal plane

Comment: This will increase the capacitive loading due to the close proximity. Different matching component values will be needed at least.

Answer (score 0):

The ground/reference plane to either microstrip or coplanar waveguide doesn't have to be on the bottom layer of a 4 layer PCB.  If you are looking to reduce the width of your impedance controlled traces, you can certainly use either layer 2 or 3 for the reference plane to reduce the height.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. Altium have published a document about permitivity (Core versus Prepreg) : https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/using-prepreg-vs-core-for-controlled-impedance-routing?utm_content=buffer25b6b&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer&fbclid=IwAR01dKdckLU_Giiw3cwKy0arJFx5Rx1CY_ErdbR0oSCQ9C_qs1I34ORHfSk

Comment: Yes, the key point that I take away from this article is to work with the board fabrication shop to settle on readily available board material/s (call this out specifically in your fab notes), and stackup.  Once you have these settled, you can finalize your design.